# category product photo are not add my frontpage

Tags: laravel

everything  is  ok but not  show  the  category page.it  is  the  code  which i used  that my project upload all image

```
if ($request->file('image')){
            $file = $request->file('image');
            $photo = time().$file->getClientOriginalName();
            $destination =public_path() . '/uploads/category';
            $file->move($destination, $photo);
            $category->image= $photo;
        }else{
            $category->image= 'dummy_cat.png';
        }
```

it  is  controller  code

'featuredCategories'=>Category::Where('status',1)->where('isFeatured',1)->get(),
its  my  front  page code

```
@foreach($featuredCategories as $category)
                        <div class="col-sm-2">
                            <a href="{{route('category.show',$category->slug)}}"
                               class="tt-promo-box tt-one-child hover-type-2">
                                <img src="{{asset('uploads/category'.$category->image)}}"**strong text**
                                     data-src="{{asset('uploads/category'.$category->image)}}" alt="">
                                <div class="tt-description">
                                    <div class="tt-description-wrapper">
                                        <div class="tt-background"></div>
                                        <div class="tt-title-small">{{strtoupper($category->name)}}</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                            @endforeach
```

it  is  my front  page  image
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VMK1z.png)
"look #male #female  category  add  but  not show the  category upload  photo" that is  that  main problem i face this ..

not  show  the  just  image my front  page

Comment: Can you view-source and share the url that was generated by the asset function? It could be that the path isn't being generated as expected.  If you copy the url, can you load that separately in the browser?

Comment: than you sir..done